# How do I find out where the response from dialogflow comes from?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm not a developer, so this is a little above my head.

My team has implemented a project in dialogflow, one for an old app and one from a new app. I have basic access to the old dialogflow account and I can see that it has an intent called glossaries, same intent name as in the new one. In glossaries, there is a training phrase called "What is a red talk?". This phrase only works in one of my apps and I need to know why.

[image]

There is no default response or anything under context. If I copy that curl link into a terminal, the payload doesn't return with any information.

I found the API for the new app and red talks is definitely not in the payload when I do a GET/all. There may be an old API somewhere, but no one knows where.

Where can I find this information? I'm very confused and all the basic training for dialogflow points to default response, which we're not using. I have read through the docs. I have searched the three company github repos that have the application in the name but I have not found anything. I am looking for an app.intent phrase with glossaries in it or just the word glossaries.

I have found only this json and a glossaryTest.php that doesn't seem helpful:

```
"meta": {
    "total": 2,
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 10,
    "sort": "createdAt",
    "direction": "desc",
    "load-more": false
},
"results": [
    {
        "term": "This is a term",
        "definition": "This is a definition",
        "links": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "url": "http:\/\/example.com\/1",
                "title": "KWU Course: Lead Generation 36:12:3",
                "ordering": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "url": "http:\/\/example.com\/2",
                "title": "",
                "ordering": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There is also a json with a lot data for API calls but no glossaries there either.

If we're using fulfillment to handle these intents, I don't see a fullfillment header like google docs say there should be. I may not have full access so perhaps I would be viewing more information in the screen if I had that, I have no idea. The devs who created this are long gone. The devs who also created the new app are also long gone.

Am I missing an API in my environment documentation? Is the intent hard coded? I suspect it was. How do I prove that or move forward?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your intent are somehow hard-coded [0], or defined through the UI.

> Each intent has a setting to enable fulfillment. If an intent requires
>   some action by your system or a dynamic response, you should enable
>   fulfillment for the intent. If an intent without fulfillment enabled
>   is matched, Dialogflow uses the static response you defined for the
>   intent. [2]

Perhaps you are using a custom integration [1]. So, unless you are using static response (those you see in the UI), the frontend code may be managed by your project API (not Dialogflow API), and perhaps the content modified before performing any further or eventually returning the response.

As I understand you should contact your colleagues for understanding about the integration solution they have created. Or otherwise if the Intent has been created through the API, look for its relative files where there may be They may have created the integration through the SDK, while picking up training data from a source out of the codebase. So perhaps you cannot see it directly in the code. Nonetheless, you should be able to access it through the UI once it has been created.

In case my answer was not of your help, please do not hesitate to further clarify your needs, perhaps providing some further information.

[0] https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/manage-intents#create_intent

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations

[2] https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview

Comment: my team was let go shortly after i posted this due to covid-19 issues, sorry for not responding sooner